# Specifically what kind of Integer does the .setWidth or .setHeight use?

Tags: java, android

So i'm wanting to make a button half as wide as my screen. I want it to work on any device screen size so typing in pixel values is not an option. I am getting my Integer from this code.

```
   String widthString = String.valueOf(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
   double widthDouble = Double.parseDouble(widthString);
   double result = widthDouble / 2;     
   String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
   int myNum = Integer.parseInt(resultString);
```

Then when i run the Integer into the Button like this.

```
  Button myButton = new Button(this);
  myButton.setWidth(myNum);
```

I get an error when i try to run it...any ideas on how to make it work. I'm open for any other methods you might suggest also.

Thanks

Comment: What error? There are thousands of errors, simply stating that you get an error is completely unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely getting a `NumberFormatException` since dividing an integer by 2 results in a number ending in `.5` The dot will cause `parseInt()` to fail, integers have no periods.

You *could* just `catch` the Exception, but I suggest you just cast the resulting `double` to an `int` because `getWidth()` returns an integer anyways, so you cannot go out of bounds. I also do not see the point of the String nonsense unless you are displaying these numbers in a `TextView` or something similar.

Eg

```
int myNum = (int) (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
double widthDouble = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2;
int myNum = (int) widthDouble;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using layout weights, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="My Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a NumberFormatException because you are getting a non-integer result when you divide by 2 and convert to a string.

```
Integer.parseInt("1.5")
```

This throws a NumberFormatException.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
>
> Throws:
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

A non-integer string will throw the NumberFormatException here.

A simple cast from your getWidth() call to store the width as an int should work.